# Docker compose Nginx inner container returns a 404 when its accessed through an outer container

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, cypress

I have a docker compose with a few services interconnected, i.e. front-end, back-end and a DB.

My intention is to run a set of end to end tests in a separate container using cypress pointing to the front-end that is running in the docker compose. For this, I run the outer container in the same network as the front-end i.e. `mynetwork`.

`docker run --network="mynetwork" e2e:latest /bin/bash -c "node_modules/cypress/bin/cypress run"`

The problem I'm having is that cypress shows a Nginx 404 error in the browser when it tries to connect to `http://front-end:80`. It seems like it can properly reach the service but for some reason Nginx is showing **404 Not Found nginx/1.14.2**.

[404 Not Found - nginx/1.14.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpDsD.png)

Comment: anything in the frontend webserver logs?

Comment: I look at the `access.log` and I only see the requests I'm doing from the host to `http://localhost` but I don't see the requests that the outer container is doing to `http://front-end`.

Comment: if you don't see the logs, could it be that the requests are not making it through then?

Comment: I have the feeling it's a misconfiguration in Nginx somewhere. Weird thing is that I can see the app correctly from the host machine but from the outer container I only see that disturbing 404 error. I think it's correctly hitting the container because I see the Nginx logo text in the error page but I wonder why it can't find the sources when the container makes the request.